# mysql can not connect to local MySQL server through socket

Tags: mysql, linux, linux-mint

Because MySQL was giving problems lately I was trying to delete and reinstall it again.

But as the title says: "MySQL can not connect to local MySQL server through socket"
I have tried for days to figure this out but i am new to Linux so wasn't getting far.

So first i did successfully this:

```
sudo su

service zoneminder stop

apt remove zoneminder

apt purge zoneminder

apt autoremove
```

then `mysql -u root -p` giving problems:

> "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

then I tried to restart MySQL again with: `/etc/init.d/mysql start`
answer:

> [....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for
>   mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error
>   code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for
>   details.

so I did: `systemctl status mysql.service`

> l.service ● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
>   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Thu
>   2018-06-14 16:0   Process: 5966 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld
>   (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)   Process: 5959
>   ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exit  Main
>   PID: 5966 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 5967
>   (mysql-systemd-s    CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
>              └─control
>                ├─5967 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
>                └─6001 sleep 1

Not any clue what to do now... anyone?

> > > edit: 
> > >       In am not really now this "linux language" stuff but here some quotes from mysql error log:
>
> 2018-06-15T10:56:01.251215Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load
>   completed at 180615 12:56:01 mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't
>   exist 2018-06-15T10:56:01.251348Z 0 [ERROR] Can't open the
>   mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
>   2018-06-15T10:56:01.251477Z 0 [ERROR] unknown option
>   '--NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' 2018-06-15T10:56:01.251489Z 0 [ERROR]
>   Aborting
>
> mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist 2018-06-15T10:55:30.931509Z
>   0 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade
>   to create it. 2018-06-15T10:55:30.931613Z 0 [ERROR] unknown option
>   '--NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' 2018-06-15T10:55:30.931633Z 0 [ERROR]
>   Aborting

Comment: Is there anything written to the server's error log? And can you add some more details to your question, eg. the OS you are using?

Comment: oh yeah sorry. i am using linux mint 18.3 (64 bit). Error servers log? how do i get these?

Comment: i find the error log but these is 19377 characters long... to long to post here. What do you want to know?

Comment: Well, if there is anything relevant for this question, add it to the question ;)

Comment: something like this? (see question)

Comment: Does https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165364/why-none-of-the-sql-modes-are-recognized-by-mysql help? DId you probably install another version than you've had before?